# Passing url image dynamically to another page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm running a site on wordpress and have an html script for editing images. What i'm trying to do is to create a button under each image, and when a user clicks on the button a new page is opened to edit the image.

I know how to create a button, build the page with the script on...etc, but i'm not sure to pass the image url dynamically to the script page so that specific image can be edited. I have lots of images, so creating static pages from each of the images wont work.

I'm a bit lost so any ideas are welcome. Even if there is a better way for doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are several options. I assume, from the PHP tag, that you have access to PHP.
I also make the assumption you have an ID for each image.

```
<?php echo '<a href="image-edit.html?id=` . $id . `">Edit this image</a>`; ?>
```

You will need to change the variables, but this should work when you have a variable for the idea.
To continue, on that page you can get that variable by using the following in PHP:

```
$_GET['id']
```

This is a modifiable variable by itself by the way (something I recently found out). Users can also manipulate this by editing the link in the address bar.

Or, if you have the variables generated in the html and want to use javascript, see [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp)